# Restoring DB snapshot in AWS showing different configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am restoring a snapshot in AWS from my old AWS database, but it instead of using my old configuration like my t2.db.micro and public access, it is suggesting "other" configurations.

Here my logic: When I want to restore a snapshot, I mostly want to create exactly the one I used before. So why would AWS suggest another "random" config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a new DB instance is created when you restore. I should read the docs :)

Comment: Hi. If you refer to docs, a link would be helpful.